# Is there any way to pause a Windows shutdown so that a forms.closing method can complete?

Tags: vb.net, windows, winforms

I am trying to put some information in a database when windows begins to shutdown. In my application I am handling the Form.Closing event. However, Windows will go ahead and shut down and my Method doesn't have time to complete. Is there any way to pause the shutdown long enough to handle the shutdown? Here is my method that I am currently using.

```
Private Sub frmMain_Closing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing
        If e.CloseReason = CloseReason.WindowsShutDown Then
            _logger.Debug("Hit frmMain_Closing1")
            NewEvent(Events.SystemShutdownNormal)
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)
            _logger.Debug("Hit frmMain_Closing 2")
        End If
    End Sub
```

Every time I am logging twice to a log file using the `_logger.Debug("Hit...")` However, only the first time I call it is getting written to the file. I have tried the method of setting `e.Cancel = True`, but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Does that call flush to the file or only write to a buffer?

Comment: @BenVoigt Tbh, I'm not sure. I didn't write that portion. I just know that we use that to log to a file. That's the only call I make, but I'm not sure on the mechanics behind it.

Comment: Putting a `Sleep` in there might be a bad idea.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yeah, I have since removed it.

Comment: The days of blocking a shutdown are over and done with, that did not work *at all*.  You can pinvoke ShutdownBlockReasonCreate() so you can display a message on the screen that Windows displays when apps refuse to quit.  You'll have to convince the user you are doing something Very Important Indeed so he won't click the ignore button.  Much like me, he *will* ignore it if you take more than 5 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sorry for this misformation.**
<strike>In short, there is no way to delay or cancel a Windows shutdown. It will tap all processes "nicely" to exit, then go through and kill any ones that haven't.</strike>
You can delay shutdown until your process finishes. To do this, you need to use `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate()`.

You should be hooking the WM_QUERYENDSESSION message in order to get the opportunity to do something. You'll need to override the WinProc, deal with the message, and then call the base WinProc. Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionending(v=vs.110).aspx (scroll down to remarks.)

<strike>Keep in mind that Windows won't wait forever, but this will give you a bit of advance notification.. hopefully enough that you have a chance to do whatever you need to do. Prioritize the important stuff first, in the hopes that it finishes before the process is killed.</strike>

Once you've hooked WM_QUERYENDSESSION, you should call 
`ShutdownBlockReasonCreate()` to block shutdown until your app is finished closing. Once finished, call `ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy()`. For more information, see [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms700677(v=vs.85).aspx) (scroll down to "Applications that must block shutdown should use the new shutdown reason API").

The PInvoke declares can be [found here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.shutdownblockreasoncreate) and [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy).

Comment: You can intercept the message and prompt the user to cancel shutdown then programatically shutdown once you are done cleaning up.  Something like this: 

    Private Const WM_QUERYENDSESSION As System.Int32 = &H11
    Private Const WM_CANCELMODE As System.Int32 = &H1F

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef ex As Message)
        If ex.Msg = WM_QUERYENDSESSION Then
            'cancel the message
            MsgBox("Please cancel shutdown", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/c shutdown /s")
        End If
    End Sub

Comment: @Neelix Reivsed my answer. MS created new APIs to deal with this.

Comment: Yeah, I got to playing with this today. I had to change a registry setting to allow programs to pause shutdown. I followed the method found here: http://www.trishtech.com/2011/07/turn-off-auto-closing-of-programs-at-shutdown-in-windows-7/

Once I did this, I could use `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate()` to create a reason on Frm_Load and my program was able to run until I called the `ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy()` method. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for commenting with the registry setting, too.